# Загрузка большого количества файлов в Android

Tags: android, java

Есть такой код загрузки файлов в асинктаск:

```
wl.acquire();
    File cacheDir = getExternalCacheDir();
    InputStream stream = null;
    BufferedInputStream bif = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    Bitmap[] cachedBitmaps = new Bitmap[params.length];
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    URL url = null;
    try {
        for(int i=0; i < params.length; i++){
            String[] splits = params[i].split("/");
        String fileName = splits[splits.length-1];
        File newFile = new File(cacheDir+"/"+fileName);             
        url = new URL(params[i]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            connection.connect();
            stream = connection.getInputStream();
        bif = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
        fout = new FileOutputStream(newFile, false);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int b;

            while( (b = bif.read(buffer)) != -1 ){
            fout.write(buffer);
        }

        publishProgress();

        stream.close();
        bif.close();
        fout.close();
        connection.disconnect();
        }
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        LogUtil.log(e.getMessage());
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        LogUtil.log(e.getMessage());
    }

    wl.release();
```

Все работает, но есть один интересный момент. В эмуляторе загружаются все картинки, но на девайсах загружается только часть. Такое ощущение, что он их пропускает или не сбрасывается буфер. Поставил закрытие потоков выше в коде - стало лучше, но все равно картинки не все успевают загрузиться. Почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кому интересно: нужно поменять вызов fout.write(buffer); на версию со смещением и количеством байт, тогда правильный цикл будет выглядеть так:

```
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
int count;
while ((count = bif.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
    fos.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: это баг андроида?

Comment: честно говоря не знаю. Может Java SE, может самой ОС. В работе с потоками. Главное помнить об этом:)